# Problema com sobrecarga de operador

Tags: c++, c++11

Os erros ocorrem quando passo o objeto da classe `Name_pairs` pelo operador de saída `<<` e pelo operador comparativo `==`.

Header:

```
    class Name_pairs
    {
    public:
        void read_names(); 
        void read_ages();
        void print() const; 
        void sort(); 
        const std::vector<std::string>& get_name() const { return name; } 
        const std::vector<double>& get_age() const { return age; }    
    private:
        std::vector<std::string>name; 
        std::vector<double>age;     
    };
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Name_pairs objeto;
    objeto.read_names();
    objeto.read_ages();
    objeto.sort();
    objeto.print();

    Name_pairs objetoDois;
    objetoDois.read_names();
    objetoDois.read_ages();
    objetoDois.sort();
    objetoDois.print();

    if(objeto == objetoDois) cout << "iguais!"; // erro no operador == ;
    else cout << "não são iguais!";
    cout << objeto;  // erro no operador << ;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

cpp de definições:

```
    void Name_pairs::read_names()
    {
        cout << "Entre com os nomes desejados, digite 'SemNome' para               finalizar a lista." << endl;
        string NomesVetor; 

        while (cin >> NomesVetor && NomesVetor != "SemNome")
        {
            for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x) // confere se há nomes duplicados 
            {
                if (name[x] == NomesVetor) cout << "Nome repetido." << endl;
            }

            name.push_back(NomesVetor);
        }
    }

    void Name_pairs::read_ages()
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x)
        {
            cout << "Idade de " << name[x] << ": " << endl;
            double IdadesVetor; 
            cin >> IdadesVetor;
            age.push_back(IdadesVetor);
        }
    }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Name_pairs& np)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < np.get_name().size(); ++x)
        os << '(' << np.get_name()[x] << ', ' << np.get_age()[x] << ')' << endl;

    return os;

}

 bool operator==(const Name_pairs& a, const Name_pairs& b )
{
    if(a.get_name().size() != b.get_name().size() || a.get_age().size() != b.get_age().size())
    return false;

    for (size_t x = 0; x <a.get_name().size(); ++x)
    {
        if (a.get_name()[x] != b.get_name()[x]) return false;
        if (a.get_age()[x] != b.get_age()[x]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool operator!=(const Name_pairs& a, const Name_pairs& b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

Lembrando que: O codigo compila se for removido

```
 if(objeto == objetodois)cout << "iguais!"; // erro no operador ==
        else cout << "não são iguais!";
        cout << objeto;  // erro no operador <<
```

da main.

Comment: Coloque mais trechos da `main()`, sequer dá para saber o tipo das variáveis usadas só com este trecho.

Comment: Pronto, editei com a main.

Comment: Esse código sequer compila. Tem erros primários. Coloque um [mcve], não vai adiantar jogar códigos aleatórios, isto não vai te ajudar.

Comment: Deixe-me explicar melhor. Como eu havia dito, o código compila mas o erro só se apresenta **se eu chamar o `<<` e o `== `no `main`**, eu passei o tipo que eu quero comparar, no caso duas classes com dois vetores: um string e um double em cada. E também mostrei a função que sobrecarrega. Não foi a intenção se passei a impressão de "copiar colar e resolvam meus problemas", irei também mostrar as funções para preencher meus vetores, se isso ajuda a entender o funcionamento.

Comment: Quando você fizer um [mcve] você me avisa, por enquanto não dá para responder, chega ao ponto de usar variáveis que não existem, este código não é real.

Comment: Notei alguns erros que você havia comentado, desculpe por eles. Enfim, a única coisa que não coloquei foi a função sort() que serve apenas para o que o próprio nome dela sugere, se faltar algo por favor me avise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marv,

O seu código não está completo, portanto fica impossível avaliá-lo. Ainda assim exemplifico abaixo a implementação de ambos operadores em uma classe qualquer.

É importante lembrar que para que o exemplo compile o método operator<< deve ser declarado como "friend" da classe, permitindo que um objeto desta seja passado por referência ao standard output (vulgo *cout*).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Classe
{
public:
    std::string texto;
    int numero;

    bool operator==(const Classe& cmp)
    {
        return this->numero == cmp.numero && this->texto == cmp.texto;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Classe& obj)
    {
        os << obj.texto;
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Classe objeto_1, objeto_2;

    objeto_1.numero = 1;
    objeto_1.texto = "Objeto 1";

    objeto_2.numero = 2;
    objeto_2.texto = "Objeto 2";

    if (objeto_1 == objeto_2)
    {
        std::cout << "Os objetos comparados são iguais." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << objeto_1 << " é diferente de " << objeto_2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter conseguido te ajudar.

**Editado:**

Consegui entender o código postado e fazer as modificações para que ele funcione corretamente.

O modificador "friend" quando utilizado torna a função um "agregado" da classe e não propriamente um membro, o que não permite a sintaxe especificada na minha resposta acima.

Ao remover este modificador utiliza-se somente 1 parâmetro para os operadores == e !=, sendo que este parâmetro é comparado com o valor apontado pelo ponteiro "this" da classe atual, conforme o código demonstra abaixo:

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Name_pairs
{
public:
    void read_names();
    void read_ages();
    void print() const;
    void sort();

    const std::vector<std::string>& get_name() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    const std::vector<double>& get_age() const
    {
        return age;
    }

    bool operator==(const Name_pairs& a)
    {
        if (a.get_name().size() != this->get_name().size() || a.get_age().size() != this->get_age().size())
            return false;

        for (size_t x = 0; x < a.get_name().size(); ++x)
        {
            if (a.get_name()[x] != this->get_name()[x]) return false;
            if (a.get_age()[x] != this->get_age()[x]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Name_pairs& a)
    {
        return !((*this) == a);
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < this->get_name().size(); ++x)
            os << '(' << this->get_name()[x] << ", " << this->get_age()[x] << ')' << std::endl;

        return os;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string>name;
    std::vector<double>age;
};

void Name_pairs::read_names()
{
    std::cout << "Entre com os nomes desejados, digite 'SemNome' para               finalizar a lista." << std::endl;
    std::string NomesVetor;

    while (std::cin >> NomesVetor && NomesVetor != "SemNome")
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x) // confere se há nomes duplicados
        {
            if (name[x] == NomesVetor) std::cout << "Nome repetido." << std::endl;
        }

        name.push_back(NomesVetor);
    }
}

void Name_pairs::read_ages()
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x)
    {
        std::cout << "Idade de " << name[x] << ": " << std::endl;
        double IdadesVetor;
        std::cin >> IdadesVetor;
        age.push_back(IdadesVetor);
    }
}
```

Foi possível compilar e utilizar normalmente (exceto pela ausência da implementação de algumas funções) a classe com o código postado.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado pela dica do "Friend", foi muito útil. Quanto ao post, eu já editei algumas vezes e havia esquecido de colocar o código da classe, desses ai eu só deixei de fora as funções que não precisam ser implementadas para que a parte que eu preciso aconteça. Preciso comparar o vetor de idade e outro de nomes de um objeto com outros dois de outro objeto da mesma classe. Enfim, é possível?

Comment: Sim, é possível... vai ser necessário implementar a comparação entre eles através do operator== manualmente. O operador só vai facilitar o trabalho depois de implementado para comparar dois objetos do mesmo tipo.

Comment: Sim sim! Justamente, eu fiz isso com os `for`s para deixar bem claro mas mesmo assim recebo esse erro.

Comment: Editei novamente minha resposta, com os ajustes necessários para que teu código funcione, dá uma conferida... Espero que tenha sido útil.

Comment: @Marv, vale ressaltar que algumas partes da sua implementação estão mais complicadas que o necessário. O `std::vector` já define um operador de comparação e portanto basta comparar os vetores diretamente e não percorrer comparando seus valores um a um. Já na função `read_names`, você pode substituir seu loop que verifica se o nome já existe pela utilização do `std::find` declarado no arquivo `algorithm`.

Comment: @Marv, repare que não é necessário declarar os operadores como `friend` ou membros da classe no seu caso já que eles dependem apenas da interface pública da sua classe. Seu código estava correto, porém você não havia declarado os operadores no header então a função `main` não conseguia encontra-los.

Sempre que possível, prefira declarar os operadores como funções livres pois assim você minimiza a dependência nos valores privados da sua classe e no caso de operadores simétricos como o de comparação você evita possíveis problemas onde `a == b` não é equivalente a `b == a` devido a conversões.

Comment: Opa, valeu pelas dicas. Sim, eu sei que muitas funções membros não é algo bom, eu havia tentado fazer de algumas formas mas não havia conseguido, sou bem iniciante ainda. Essa do vector vai ser bem útil.